# Apache Beam Error when inserting into BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Apache Beam 2.9.0 using Google Cloud DataFlow.

I'm getting an error which seems to be related to schema when trying to insert into BigQuery:

```
RuntimeError: Could not successfully insert rows to BigQuery table [project:mlpipeline.twitter_posts]. Errors: [<InsertErrorsValueListEntry errors: [<ErrorProto debugInfo: u'' location: u'text' message: u'Invalid NUMERIC value: RT @Deep_In_Depth: 3 Advanced Python Functions for Data Scientists #DeepLearning #MachineLearning #ArtificialIntell\u2026' reason: u'invalid'>] index: 0>, <InsertErrorsValueListEntry errors: [<ErrorProto debugInfo: u'' location: u'text' message: u'Invalid NUMERIC value: What Is Deep Learning? #DeepLearning #MachineLearning #ArtificialIntelligence #DataScience #DL #ML #DS #AI #DNN #NeuralNetworks #NLP #GPU #TensorFlow #Keras #Pytorch #Python #HPC #Automation #AutonomousCar #Quant' reason: u'invalid'>] index: 1>] [while running 'generatedPtransform-20667']
at _flush_batch (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py:1380)
at finish_bundle (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery.py:1368)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle (common.py:365)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnInvoker.invoke_finish_bundle (common.py:361)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method (common.py:697)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._reraise_augmented (common.py:724)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner._invoke_bundle_method (common.py:699)
at apache_beam.runners.common.DoFnRunner.finish (common.py:705)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish (operations.py:508)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish (operations.py:507)
at apache_beam.runners.worker.operations.DoOperation.finish (operations.py:506)
at process_bundle (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/bundle_processor.py:441)
at process_bundle (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py:237)
at do_instruction (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py:221)
at <lambda> (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py:170)
at _execute (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker.py:135)
```

Code:

```
# Make explicit BQ schema for output tables
    bigqueryschema_json = '{"fields": [' \
                          '{"name":"id","type":"STRING"},' \
                          '{"name":"text","type":"NUMERIC"},' \
                          '{"name":"user_id","type":"STRING"},' \
                          '{"name":"sentiment","type":"FLOAT"},' \
                          '{"name":"posted_at","type":"TIMESTAMP"}' \
                          ']}'
    bigqueryschema = parse_table_schema_from_json(bigqueryschema_json)
```

I have change text field in `bigqueryschema_json` to `STRING` and `NUMERIC`, but same issue.

Complete code [here](https://github.com/TDehaene/blogposts/blob/master/got_sentiment/4_streaming_pipeline/streaming_tweet.py):
Any details how to debug this error?

Comment: `text` field should definitevely not be a `NUMERIC`, as the error states (`location: u'text' message: u'Invalid NUMERIC value...'`), but rather a `STRING`. Could you provide the schema of the destination table? It may have been created with `text` as `NUMERIC`. If this is the case, you must need to recreate the table with the right types.

Comment: That was it, table was created initially with wrong NUMERIC field but for some reason my Console didnt show the newly created tables. After deleting table, using STRING field all is good. Thanks